# Which file format, to print the largest pictures without losing quality?

Tags: printing

I'd like to get JPGs from https://old.reddit.com/r/lakeporn/top/, https://old.reddit.com/r/Beachporn/top/, https://old.reddit.com/r/BotanicalPorn/ printed, to hang them on my apartment's walls, in the most gigantic print size without any loss of quality.

I don't have a photo printer.  So I'll save the pictures to an USB, bring the USB to a photo printer (like Costco), and have Costco print them.

1. Does it matter what file format I use?
2. If it does, what format ought I convert the JPGs to?
3. Any recommendations other than IrfanView for the conversions?

Comment: They are already JPG's, why do you want to convert the formats at all?

Comment: @user10216038 a newcomer doesn't understand what is intuitive to many others. That's why an explanation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not matter.

There are just a few things that matter:

- compression ratio/quality level: If the file is already strongly compressed you may see artifacts on the final print. Like if you have a jpg at quality 100% and compress it down to 1%, you will clearly see this. This artifacts also appear on better quality levels, so you should try to get the files as uncompressed as possible (does not apply to lossless compression)
- resolution: Should be clear, that you will have no good prints if the file is only 4x3 pixels

Conversion into other file formats will in the best case do nothing to the photos, but in worst case it lowers the quality of the photo, because of the different compression methods.

Most printing services are fine with jpg because it is one of the most used formats and surly the most costumers send their files as jpg.